# How to build a pydantic model for List[List[int]]?

Tags: python, list, pydantic

I would like to use a Pydantic model to validate a `List[List[int]]`. I'm a newbie in Pydantic. Here is some test code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import List, Optional

class Scenes(BaseModel):
    scenes_start_duration_ms: List[List[int]]

class Video(BaseModel):
    video_id: str
    scenes_start_duration_ms: Optional[Scenes] = None
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = {
        "scenes_start_duration_ms": [
            [0, 1234],
            [1568, 2769],
            [4671, 734],
            [5405, 1268],
        ],
        "video_id": "kl",
    }

    m = Scenes.model_validate(response)
    print(m)

    m = Video.model_validate(response)
    print(m)
```

Output is:

```
scenes_start_duration_ms=[[0, 1234], [1568, 2769], [4671, 734], [5405, 1268]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/hdd/P/UW/clipmaker/test-list.py", line 30, in <module>
    m = Video.model_validate(response)
  File "/media/hdd/P/UW/clipmaker/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 509, in model_validate
    return cls.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Video
scenes_start_duration_ms
  Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of Scenes [type=model_type, input_value=[[0, 1234], [1568, 2769],...671, 734], [5405, 1268]], input_type=list]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_type
```

I can't understand what the problem is?

**Update:**

It works for the Video with the modification from:

```
    scenes_start_duration_ms: Optional[Scenes] = None
```

to:

```
    scenes_start_duration_ms: Optional[List[List[int]]] = None
```

However, I am looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from typing import List, Optional

class Scenes(BaseModel):
    scenes_start_duration_ms: List[List[int]]

class Video(BaseModel):
    video_id: str
    scenes_start_duration_ms: Optional[Scenes] = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = {
        "scenes_start_duration_ms": {
            "scenes_start_duration_ms": [
                [0, 1234],
                [1568, 2769],
                [4671, 734],
                [5405, 1268],
            ]
        },
        "video_id": "kl",
    }

try:
    video_instance = Video(**response)
    print(video_instance)
    print("Validation successful!")
except ValidationError as e:
    print(f"Validation failed: {e}")
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I understand your approach. However, I received a response from the database without double curly braces {{}}.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write validator for this...!

```
@validator("scenes_start_duration_ms", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def validate_scenes(cls, value):
     .......your logic comes here

       return value
```